# C - taking categorized data from text into struct

Tags: c, struct, fread

I am working on a project with C/C++ . I have a problem with reading from file .
// edit for share more code

I have a structs like :

```
struct card{
    char color;
    char suit;
    char num[3];
    char turned[5];
    card *next;
};
struct cardlist{
    card *top;
    int counter;
    cardlist *nextlist;

    void create();
    bool push(card *newcard);
    void pop();
    void showlist();
    bool isempty();

};
```

I have to read from 'solitare.txt' . and create a single linked list. solitare.txt is like :

```
B C 3 Up
B C 6 Up
R D 4 Up
B C 2 Up
R H 3 Up
R D 8 Up
******
R H 6 Up
******
R H 8 Down
B S 9 Up
******
B S 2 Down
B C K Down
B S Q Up
```

My Functions :

```
void cardlist::create(){
    top = NULL ;
    counter = 0;
}
bool cardlist::isempty(){
    if(top == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void cardlist::showlist(){
    if(isempty()){
        cout << "Liste bos." << endl ;
        return;
    }
    card *temp = new card;
    temp = top;
    while(temp){
        cout << temp->color << temp->suit << temp->num << temp->turned << endl;
        temp = temp->next ;
    }
}
bool cardlist::push(card *newcard){

    card *temp = new card ;
    temp = newcard;
    temp->next = NULL ;

    if(top == NULL){
        top = temp ;
        counter++;
        return true;
    }else{
        temp->next = top ;
        top = temp ;
        counter++;
        return true ;
    }
    return false;
}
void cardlist::pop(){
    if(isempty()){
        cout << "liste bos kart silinemez." << endl ;
        return ;
    }
    card *removed = top ;
    card *temp ;
    temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    counter--;
    delete removed;

}
```

and my main()

```
FILE *fptr = fopen("solitaire.txt","r+");
    if(fptr == NULL){
        cout << "dosya acilamadi" << endl ;
    }

    cardlist l1;
    l1.create();

    int ch;

    long pos = ftell(fptr);

    while( (ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF){
        fseek(fptr,pos,SEEK_SET);
        cout << "girildi" ;
        card *temp = new card;

        if(ch == (int)'*')
        {
            break ;
        }else
        {

        fread(temp,sizeof(card),1,fptr);

        l1.push(temp);
        l1.showlist();
        cout << endl ;
        pos = ftell(fptr);
        }
    }
```

I used ftell() to take cursor back , because at line (ch = fgetc(fptr)) cursor moves forward (I suppose)

The problem is output is not same as 'solitare.txt' . There are lots of inexplicable character in the output , Why the characters are crashed ?

Comment: So what problem do you actually have? And what do you mean by grouping ? Also there is no such thing as C/C++

Comment: `fread(&temp,sizeof(card),1,fptr)` This doesn't work. The biggest concern is the pointer.

Comment: meaning fptr ? if so maybe you could post more code ? Also do you get compilation error ? If so paste it please

Comment: The problem is I can't take data by using fread() because of "******" . I mean by grouping ; I should take data (until ******)into card structs and insert them into a single list.Problem is not about creating list , it is about taking data until ****** . after ****** line I should continue to take and create list until other ****** .

Comment: I don't get compilation error . fptr is file pointer
fptr = fopen("data.txt","r+")

Comment: Your file is a text file, so you can't read a whole `card` data at once. You'd have to read your file line by line and assemble the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is make an array of lists like so:

```
std::list< std::list< card > > myListOfLists;
```

Then when you encounter the `******` in your file, just make a new list with your struct then do:

```
myListofLists.push_back(newList);
```

Comment: Thank you laiello , but I have to do this part with using C , not C++

Comment: @conrad, so why did you use the C++? I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing this in C, or C++?  This will make a big difference as file i/o is generally handled in very different ways.  @Iaiello provided a C++ answer relying on iostreams that is not available in C.  Your use of `fread` suggests that you probably want a C solution.  So, here it is.

You can pull a single char from the file using fgetc, and then test it to see if it is an asterisk and put it back into the file to be read later.  The code for this would look like

```
int ch;
while( (ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
{

    if(ch == (int)'*')
    {
        //code to point to different list.  Perhaps switch statement and state variable
    }else
    {
        fread(&temp,sizeof(card),1,fptr);
        //code to apend temp to list
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Degustaf , with addition of ftell() function it seems that I am close to solve . the line  while( (ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)  is moves cursor forward and I tried to take it back.I think  it will work but I can't solve that output forms inexplicable characters